# How to divide two columns such that one takes up 1/3 of the page and the other takes up the rest of the 2/3?

Tags: two-column, resume, page

## For my Resume

I would like to have the following format:

```
                                             **Title** 
|             1/3 column              |                       2/3 column                      |
|                                     |                                                       |
|                                     |                                                       |
:                                     :                                                       :
'                                     '                                                       '
```

I've tried some google searches for 'offset two-column Latex' and also tried some examples but with no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please explain which data should be in column 1, which data in column 2? Which margins do you want to use? Do you use outdated class `resume.cls`? Please explain your issue better ...

Comment: have a look at this class, it can provide you with some inspiration :)
https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV

Comment: Also, show us what you try by including a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: The paracol package supports uneven columns.  If you want to really get fancy, look at flowframm or just format the entire page using tikz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `tabularx`: the ratio of the coefficients for `\hsize` has to be 1/2, and their sum has to be the number of columns (2):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}%
\arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize =0.667\hsize}X|>{\hsize =1.333\hsize}X|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Title} \\[0.8ex]
\hline
\lipsum[47] & \lipsum[48] \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a class that was developed for this purpose, e.g. `moderncv` and then use the command `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{7cm}` to set the left column width, as in:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{7cm}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\linewidth` is the length of the line. So you will be able to achieve the desired result with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4][1-8]
\begin{table}[!h]
    \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.33\linewidth}|p{0.6\linewidth}|}
        \hline
        \lipsum[1-2][1-2]& \lipsum[1-2][1-2]\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you don't need the `lipsum` package for that. I am using that only for demonstration purposes.
[image]